# Why is the android.widget.SearchView not expanding on single click and instead moves the icon to left side?

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

I am using `android.widget.SearchView` inside `MaterialToolbar` and have also set the correct attributes inside the menu reource file. But when I click the search icon, it doesn't expand. Instead, the search icon moves to the left side. On clicking it again, it expands but the search icon still appears inside the EditText.

**Layout file**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        app:title="@string/app_name" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**Menu file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Before clicking

[image: Before clicking]

After clicking

[image: After clicking]

[SearchView hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xNyK.jpg)

Comment: Try using `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` for the `app:actionViewClass`.

Comment: @MikeM. After using the AppCompat version, the search view expands perfectly. But after expansion, the EditText still has the search icon which disappears as soon as I start typing. Moreover, the docs for `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` are saying that you should use it only if you want to support API 7. If you are using API 11 or higher, use the framework class. That's where I am confused.

Comment: Hmm, I never knew that was the documented suggestion for `SearchView`. I'm not sure what to tell you, at this point.

Comment: @MikeM. Just another example of bad documentation. Anyway, can you suggest how to remove the search icon which appears just before typing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is it like the one in your second image? Or is it like a hint in the `EditText` part?

Comment: @MikeM. Its like a hint in the `EditText`.

Comment: Could you grab a screenshot? I'll have a look at the source.

Comment: I have added a link to the screenshot.

Comment: OK, I think you're going to have to use an action layout to get rid of the hint, because it is only set from an XML attribute. Create a separate layout file with only the `<SearchView>` in it, width of `match_parent`, height of `wrap_content`, and the key is `app:searchHintIcon="@null"`. Then change `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` to `app:actionLayout="@layout/your_search_view_layout"`. Lemme know what happens.

Comment: I just tested that, and it worked for me.

Comment: @MikeM. It worked. Now I can also customize the SearchView from that layout, right?

Comment: Yeah, inasmuch as you could anywhere, like in the `Activity`'s layout.

Comment: I guess I've found my answer. Can you elaborate on this as an answer to my post, so I can mark it as my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the documentation suggests using the framework `SearchView`, I've always found that the support/androidx `SearchView` plays nicer with the library components – e.g., `AppCompatActivity`, `MaterialToolbar`, etc. – though I'm not sure exactly what causes these little glitches. Indeed, using `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` here in lieu of `android.widget.SearchView` for the `actionViewClass` got rid of that misplaced search icon upon expanding.

However, the `AutoCompleteTextView` inside the `SearchView` still has a similar search icon as a hint because it's not ending up with the right style. I initially expected that setting the `Toolbar` as the support `ActionBar` would've integrated that with the other relevant styles for the children, but it seems `SearchView`'s style, for some reason, is normally set with a `ThemeOverlay.*.ActionBar` on the `<*Toolbar>` acting as the `ActionBar`.

Though most sources seem to indicate that the various `ThemeOverlay.*.ActionBar` styles only adjust the `colorControlNormal` attribute, they actually set the `searchViewStyle` to the appropriate `Widget.*.SearchView.ActionBar` value, too, so it's doubly important that we add a proper overlay. For example, in keeping with changing to the `androidx` version:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
    ... />
```

This could also work by setting that as the `actionBarTheme` in your `Activity`'s theme instead, but be warned that it can be overridden by attributes on the `<*Toolbar>` itself, like it would be in the given setup by `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"`.

If you're not using Material Components, `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat` styles are available as well. And if you're using only platform classes, similar styles are available in the system namespace; e.g., `@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar`.

---

The initial revision of this answer removed that hint icon manually, as at the time I was unaware of how exactly the given setup was failing. It shouldn't be necessary to do that now, but if you'd like to customize this further, that example simply replaced the menu `<item>`'s `app:actionViewClass` attribute with an `app:actionLayout` pointing to this layout:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:searchHintIcon="@null" />
```

The `searchHintIcon` setting is all that was needed for the example here, but you can set whatever applicable `SearchView` attributes you'd like.

If you're going this route, it might be preferable to set `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar"`, which includes the `searchHintIcon` setting, and ensures the correct overall style for the `SearchView`, as suggested by Artem Mostyaev in comments below.

Comment: You may use `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar"` instead of setting `app:searchHintIcon="@null"`.

Comment: That style sets several other attribute values too, though. Minimum necessary for this example is setting just the `searchHintIcon`.

Comment: Yeah. But the style gives you all the attributes to achieve the native SearchView style. I hope it could be useful for someone.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see what you meant. Good point.

Comment: Your comment was indeed useful. I didn't know that style existed, and it made me realize that there must be a "built-in" way to do that without the custom layout. I've edited the answer, in case you were using this solution and would like to update. Thanks, and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

the above method does not work for me. I don't know why but a tried this and succeed.
Refer to the search hint icon through SearchView and set it's visibility to GONE:

```
ImageView icon = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And then add this line:

```
mSearchView.setIconified(false);
```